# why the first object member was changed after creating the second object

Tags: c++, reference

Defined a class with a member as a reference type:

```
struct NodeBase{
int& val;
NodeBase(int input = 0) :val{ input }{}
};
```

Then created two object of this class type:

```
int value1 = 1, value2 = 2;
NodeBase first(value1);
NodeBase second(value2);
```

When the `first`was created, its member `val` equals to 1. However, after creating `second`the value of `val` in `first`changed to 2. Not sure why this happens.

Comment: The references are dangling, because they are bound to values that are no longer alive (namely the constructor parameter variable). It is therefore undefined behaviour to evaluate the references.

Comment: Changed to predefined variables, and problem is the same.

Comment: Doesn't matter, reference binds to the function parameter which dies at end of constructor.

Comment: Yes, the problem is the same: the references are still dangling. Change the constructor to take its argument by reference.

Comment: You haven't changed anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference binds to the function parameter `input` which goes out of scope when the constructor completes. This leaves the reference dangling.

Take a reference as parameter instead to have the reference refer to an external object.

```
NodeBase(int& input) :val{ input }{}
```

If you don't want the class to refer to external variables, make the member a plain `int` without the reference. Given you try to have a default argument which does not make sense for the non-const reference case, this is probably what you should do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass input by reference as well:

```
struct NodeBase{
    int& val;
    NodeBase(int& input) :val{ input }{}
};
```

If you don't, `val` will reference the local parameter, which doesn't exist anymore as soon as the constructor has finished. So it's undefined behavior.

Note that you can't provide your default argument `=0`  which has no meaning when keeping a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You pass `value1` as a copy that come stored into `input`. Then you save a reference to `input` variable. Not to `value1`. So when the constructor terminates, you're reference die. And became a dangling reference.

Try this:

```
struct NodeBase{
  int& val;
  NodeBase(int& input) :val{ input }{}
};
```